# Why is AM radio coming from the audio?

Tags: audio

I attached speakers to the audio of my rpi3 and can hear a faint am radio signal. It's 1080 am.

What is causing this?

Comment: Although not what you were going for, it's kind of cool in its own way....

Comment: @Brick, at least it wasn't voices telling me to play in traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wires (most likely the speaker wires, but possibly something like the power cable) are acting as an antenna. Some options you might be able to take:

- Shorten the wires
- Add [ferrite chokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) to the wires
- Replace the wires you have now with shielded wires, and tie the shield to ground.
- Put the Pi and the speakers in a metal (shielded) box.